# Creating a heatmap to visualize negative associations between pesticides and cognitive domains using Spearman correlation

Tags: r, heatmap, correlation

I am trying to create a heatmap to visualize the negative associations between pesticides and cognitive domains using Spearman's correlation. I have a dataset with 36 pesticides and 5 cognitive domains. I want to highlight the pesticides that have a significant negative correlation (p-value < 0.05) with the cognitive domains using a heatmap.

Here's a reproducible example to illustrate my problem:

```
# Generate sample data
set.seed(1)
Pesticide_names_with_numbers <- paste0("Pesticide", 1:36)
Pesticide_names_without_numbers <- paste0("Pesticide", LETTERS[1:36])
outcome_baseline <- c("zoverall_new", "zmem_new", "zatt_new", "zlang_new", "zexe_new")

# Function to calculate p-values using Spearman correlation
calculate_p_values <- function(x, y) {
  m <- cor.test(x, y, method = "spearman")
  if (m$estimate < 0 && m$p.value <= 0.05) {
    return(m$p.value)
  } else {
    return(1)
  }
}

# Calculate correlation matrix and p-values
cor_matrix <- matrix(nrow = length(Pesticide_names_with_numbers), ncol = length(outcome_baseline))
p_values <- matrix(nrow = length(Pesticide_names_with_numbers), ncol = length(outcome_baseline))

for (i in 1:length(Pesticide_names_with_numbers)) {
  for (k in 1:length(outcome_baseline)) {
    p_values[i, k] <- calculate_p_values(cogdb[[outcome_baseline[k]]], cogdb[[Pesticide_exposure_variables_adjusted[i]]])
    cor_matrix[i, k] <- cor(cogdb[[outcome_baseline[k]]], cogdb[[Pesticide_exposure_variables_adjusted[i]]], method = "spearman")
  }
}

# Set row and column names
rownames(cor_matrix) <- Pesticide_names_without_numbers
colnames(cor_matrix) <- outcome_baseline

# Create color palette
col_pal <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "red"))

# Create heat map with p-values and estimate as annotations
heatmap(cor_matrix,
        col = col_pal(100),
        main = "Negative Associations with Pesticides",
        xlab = "Cognitive Domains",
        ylab = "Pesticides",
        na.rm = TRUE,
        cexRow = 0.8,
        cexCol = 0.8)
```

In the provided example, I have simulated the data and used the cor.test function with Spearman correlation to calculate the p-values. I want to create a heatmap that highlights the negative associations with p-values less than 0.05 as red cells. However, when I try to create the heatmap using the heatmap function, I encounter some challenges.

Comment: The object `cogdb` is not present in your reproducible example.